# How to assign "app":"python app.py" in cdk.json for python or python3

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I am fairly new to cdk.  How do I set up cdk or cdk.json to run  where the python executable may be named 'python' or 'python3' depending on the platform ?

cdk init --language python creates the cdk.json on my local Windows PC with the line

```
"app": "python app.py"
```

The failure occurs when Jenkins CI/CD executes the application. Jenkins build fails because the linux based Jenkins expects 'python3'.

Current solution is to edit cdk.json when we commit to github and Jenkins auto builds the lower environments.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using python3 directly in `cdk.json`:

```
{
  "app": "python3 app.py",
  "context": {
    "@aws-cdk/core:enableStackNameDuplicates": "true",
    "aws-cdk:enableDiffNoFail": "true",
    "@aws-cdk/core:stackRelativeExports": "true",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-ecr-assets:dockerIgnoreSupport": true
  }
}
```

Or alias `python symlink` to `python3`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Nov  8 14:20 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3.8
```

Comment: My apologies.  I missed your response.  I did exactly that by switching to a linux terminal ... for many reasons.  Once I got rid of windows, problems like this one vanished.  Other developers are still stuck with the python to python3 flip at deploy time.

Answer (score 1):

I had a few problems, but in the end, using python3 in the cdk.json file made no difference. I have a windows OS. The pre-requisites were:

- Have all the configuration files (config and credentials with the correct parameters in .aws)
- Node.js and AWS Cli installed (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/work-with.html#work-with-prerequisites)

Having this, I executed the line below in my windows terminal

```html
npm install -g aws-cdk
```

Next step in my project (I use vscode), I created a folder to execute cdk (and I named it "cdk" but it could be anything).

- mkdir cdk   (to create my folder in the project)
- cd cdk      (to enter in my folder)
- cdk init app --language python   (to set the language)
- source .venv/bin/activate    (to create and activate the virtual environment)
- add "aws_cdk.aws_s3" in the requirements.txt

Before executing cdk deploy, execute the *pip install -r requirements.txt* and use *cdk synth* to test if everything is ok or if some error must be corrected.

When using git actions, use *sudo* before the npm command and add in the run command the *cd* so git can navigate until the cdk folder. Without those, I had the error that follows.
**--app is required either in command-line, in cdk.json or in ~/.cdk.json**

Here's how the deploy job was configurated in my git actions file:

```html
jobs: 
  
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest          
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2   
    - name: Set up Python           
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2 
      with: 
        python-version: '3.x'          
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v2-beta
      with: 
        node-version: '12'        
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |                  
        sudo npm install -g aws-cdk   
        cd 2_continuous_integration_and_tests/CDK
        pip install -r requirements.txt   
    - name: Deploy    
      env:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}      
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}
      run: | 
        cd 2_continuous_integration_and_tests/CDK
        cdk synth
        cdk deploy
```

Kind regards
;)